# Terraform Module Source: S3 source does not pull the latest file in Terraform Cloud

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-modules, terraform-cloud

I have a terraform module that is stored as a zip file on S3. This module/zip file is regularly re-built and updated.

In my main terraform project I'm referencing this module using an S3 source:

```
    module "my-module" {
      source = "s3::https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/staged_builds/my_module.zip"
      ... More config ...
    }
```

The issue I am having is that its really hard to get terraform cloud to deploy the latest zip file after its been initially deployed. It seems that it continues to use a cached version of the zip file sourced from S3.

The deployment is done using github actions and I did try to add the command `terraform get -update` to a build step to download the module updates.

```
  # Initialize a new or existing Terraform working directory by creating initial files, loading any remote state, downloading modules, etc.
  - name: Terraform Init
    run: terraform init

  # Update the terraform modules to get the latest versions
  - name: Update Terraform modules
    run: terraform get -update

  - name: Terraform Apply
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' && github.event_name == 'push'
    run: terraform apply -auto-approve
```

This command works great locally, However this fails to deploy the latest modules sourced from S3 when terraform cloud is used.

I have also scanned the terraform documentation for any mention on how to `taint` module sources and I haven't found and mention of it so I'm assuming modules sources cant be tainted.

The only way I have found to consistently use the latest zip file from S3 is to remove the module definition from the main terraform project, deploy it, re-add the module and deploy it again.

This is a manual and time consuming process.

Is there a better process to make sure that the terraform cloud always uses (or redownloads) the latest zip file sourced from S3 for modules?

Comment: S3 does not really support versioning, so you would probably need to transition to a backend that does.

Comment: Its not that I want to support versioning, its more that every time it deploys I would like it to download a fresh copy of the build artifact that is being used as a module source and deploy the fresh copy. Instead it seems that its caching previous sources and using those instead of redownloading the module source when deploying.